# A to Z expandable text

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking to create a section on my page where there is a list of A to Z and when you click on one of the letters it expands and gives you useful TLA.

Does anyone know how to implement this, I am extremely new to SharePoint so if someone could create a html code that i can simply copy and paste or list of instructions that would be perfect!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used this link for a couple of on premises farms.
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
It sounds like "accordion" is what you want, but another useful one is "tabs".I downloaded the jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.js and latest version of jquery.  I uploaded into my farms.  The site references a style.css.  I could not find it and removing it did not do anything to my code.  I am not a java/jquery expert and it is easy to use.
I customized each header element which will be your A-Z.  I put content into  &

elements.  I did not see any limitations on what HTML I placed in there.
Things I learned the hard way.
1.  When using their tabs solution, I had around 30 tabs and it worked fine.  I am having issues making it return to the top of the page.  At about the half-way point, it will stop scrolling to the top.  Content is there, but end-user needs to scroll.
2.  The first line of script caused an issue on my different farms.  There are different security configurations for the farms.  On one, this worked fine:"$(function() {"  On the other I had to add a "$" to it:"$(function($) {"
I hope this helps.